# How to generate an arbitrary discrete distribution? (EmpiricalDistribution vs ProbabilityDistribution)

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions

I've just started using Mma's distributions.  Suppose I want to generate an arbitrary discrete distribution by matching probabilities to outcomes.

```
p = {.4, .2, .3, .1}
vals = {0, 2, 3, 99}
```

This does not seem to be easy with `ProbabilityDistribution`, partly because it does not accept a `List` iterator.  However, it seems I can use `EmpiricalDistribution` as follows:

```
mydist = EmpiricalDistribution[p -> vals];
```

Is this in any way an abuse?  It seems to behave as I hoped.

Now someone might say, why not use `MultinomialDistribution`.  E.g.,

```
mydist02 = MultinomialDistribution[1, p]
```

But I think that's not quite as convenient because believe I will have to `Pick` from my `vals` using the returned `List`.  Or am I missing something?

Comment: That is a completely valid use of `EmpiricalDistribution`, and is documented as such. You can also do it with `ProbabilityDistribution`, but more bother for such simple cases.

Comment: BTW- if all that matters is generating variates, just use `RandomChoice` - cleaner.

Answer (score 3):

Next to using [`EmpiricalDistribution`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EmpiricalDistribution.html) the way you have done, you may build arbitrary discrete distribution by giving the definition of the PDF.

### Building Distribution by providing the PDF (or CDF)

```
probs = {0.4, 0.2, 0.3, 0.1};
vals  = {0 , 2, 3, 99};

pdf = Piecewise@Inner[ Function[ {p, v}, {p, \[FormalX] == v} ], probs, vals, List ];

dist = ProbabilityDistribution[ pdf, {\[FormalX], 0, 100, 1} ];

PDF[ dist, 0 ]
```

> 0.4

```
Histogram[ RandomVariate[ dist, 10000 ], {0, 100, 1}, "PDF" ]
```

[image: Histogram]

As an aside, from the examples given in the documentation for `EmpiricalDistribution` I noted to use of [`Boole`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Boole.html) so the `pdf` may be given as:

```
pdf = Inner[ Function[ {p,v}, p Boole[ \[FormalX] == v ], probs, vals, Plus ];
```

While using `EmpiricalDistribution` is maybe easier, using `ProbabilityDistribution` should be *more general* and thus allow more flexibility. As the examples hopefully have demonstrated, the setup may not be too cumbersome. By giving the option `Method -> "Normalize"` `ProbabilityDistribution` will - like `EmpiricalDistribution` take care of the probabilities adding up to one.

Comment: But take note of [(125314)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/125314/764) as `ProbabilityDistribution` seems to be broken for other stepsizes than $dx = 1$.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can use `MultinomialDistribution` in this way:

```
mn = MultinomialDistribution\[1, {0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.1}];
r = Thread\[Range\[4\] -> {0, 2, 3, 99}];
rv = Flatten\[Position\[#, 1] & /@ RandomVariate\[mn, 10000]] /. r;
Histogram\[rv, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Histogram]