# ProbabilityDistribution only accepts dx=1 for discrete distributions

Tags: bugs, probability-or-statistics, distributions

**Bug introduced in 10.4.1 or earlier and somewhat fixed in 12.0.0**

---

This question maybe related to [(95436)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/95436/764) but neither its answer nor the documentation for [`ProbabilityDistribution`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ProbabilityDistribution.html) state whether we may build a discrete probability distribution using a step size $dx$ different from $1$.

### Minimum Working Example

Let's say that we want to build a discrete probability distribution (say a prior distribution) for some random variable $X$ which can only take values in the range $[0,1]$. We do know that $Pr(X=\frac{1}{12}) = 0.25$, $Pr(X=\frac{1}{6})=0.5$, $Pr(X=\frac{1}{4})=0.25$ and the probability is zero for all other values.

From reading the documentation one might assume that we can use [`Piecewise`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Piecewise.html) within `ProbabilityDistribution` using a discrete range specification with $dx = \frac{1}{12}$ to build a *discrete probability distribution* matching our prior information:

```
priorDistribution = ProbabilityDistribution[
    Piecewise[
      {
        { 0.25, x == 1/12 },
        { 0.50, x == 1/6  },
        { 0.25, x == 1/4  }
      }
    ],
    { x, 0, 1, 1/12 }
]
```

But this surprisingly will not work in Version 11.0 :

```
PDF[priorDistribution, 1/4]
```

> PDF[ProbabilityDistribution[[Piecewise]  0.25    [FormalX]==1/12
> 0.5 [FormalX]==1/6
> 0.25    [FormalX]==1/4
> 0   True ,{[FormalX],0,1,1/12}],0.25]

```
RandomVariate[ priorDistribution, 10 ]
```

> RandomVariate::noimp: Sampling from ProbabilityDistribution[[Piecewise]  0.25    [FormalX]==1/12
> 0.5 [FormalX]==1/6
> 0.25    [FormalX]==1/4
> 0   True
> ,{[FormalX],0,1,1/12}] is not implemented.

Am I missing something? It seems that `ProbabilityDistribution` only accepts $dx = 1$ (I tried $dx = 2$ for a different range and it also did not work).

**Update (Version 12.0.0):**

While the above given example still does not work, the limitation with regard to *dx* has been fixed (at least with regard to dx > 1):

```
dist = ProbabilityDistribution[
      0.25 Boole[ x == 4]
    + 0.50 Boole[ x == 6]
    + 0.25 Boole[ x == 12 ]
    ,
    { x, 0, 12, 2}
]

PDF[ dist, 4 ]
```

> 0.25

**Update as of Version 12.3 (and possibly earlier?) and later**

The documentation for `ProbabilityDistribution` now shows, that  for discrete distributions, $dx$ has to be $1$. In the section Possible Issues the  [documentation](https://wolfram.com/xid/0cf19x0a9v41nyy-zes1k6) states that `TransformedDistribution` can be used to build discrete distributions with noninteger support and it in fact uses my very example. ;-)

Comment: If you try something simple like: `dist = ProbabilityDistribution[1/6, {x, 1, 11, 2}]`, it appears that it works with calculations like `Mean` or `Variance`, but not with `RandomVariate`. It doesn't work with your example at all.

Comment: I have reported the issue to WRI [CASE:3705612] and will update this post once I have gotten a feedback.

Comment: The irregular behavior with `Piecewise` has been confirmed by WRI today. I just added the `bugs` tag and header accordingly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It does seem to be broken for increments other than one. The workaround is either to rescale or else use [`EmpiricalDistribution`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EmpiricalDistribution.html)

```
priorDistribution =
  ProbabilityDistribution[
   Piecewise[{
     {0.25, x == 1},
     {0.50, x == 2},
     {0.25, x == 3}}],
   {x, 1, 12, 1}];

DiscretePlot[PDF[priorDistribution, 12 x], {x, 0, 1, 1/12}]
```

[image]

Alternatively,

```
wts = {0.25, 0.50, 0.25};

data = {1/12, 1/6, 1/4};

priorDistribution =
  EmpiricalDistribution[wts -> data];

DiscretePlot[PDF[priorDistribution, x], {x, 0, 1, 1/12}]
```

(* plot same as above  *)

Comment: Would you think this should be called a bug?

Comment: @gwr - looks like one to me.