# How to plot correct empirical distribution?

Tags: plotting, distributions

I have data that represents number of values in intervals.
So, I have intervals like: [0,1], [1,2], [2,3] and so on.
My data is [23,11,3], which means in interval [0,1] there are 23 values, inside [1,2] 11 values etc.
But when I try to plot my function I get error about sizes:

```
values = {23,11,3}
sum =  Total[values]
emp = EmpiricalDistribution[values/sum -> {  0, 1, 2, 3}]
Plot[CDF[emp][x], {x, 0, 3}, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {0, 1.1},GridLines -> Automatic]
```

Comment: There are `4` weights `{0,1,2,3}`. You need three ?

Comment: With three weights it plots 1 in interval [2,3], but 1 should be for x>3 as far as I know

Comment: For this syntax, the weights go before the data.

Comment: Still doesn't work

Comment: What you have is a discrete version (i.e., censored version) of a continuous distribution.  As such it's neither fish nor fowl.  So some *Mathematica* functions will give you the desired plots (as in my answer) but that answer won't give you correct random samples from your discrete distribution.

Answer (score 0):

It wasn't clear to me whether you wanted to impose weights to the data.

First, let's plot without weights.

```
emp = EmpiricalDistribution[values/sum]

Plot[CDF[emp][x], {x, 0, 3},
 Frame -> True,
 PlotRange -> {0, 1.1},
 GridLines -> Automatic
 ]
```

[image: Without weights]

Next, let's apply weights.

I will use {1,2,3} as an example

```
    empWeight = EmpiricalDistribution[{1, 2, 3} -> values/sum]
```

Now plot it and note the difference with the unweighted plot

```
Plot[CDF[empWeight][x], {x, 0, 3},
 Frame -> True,
 PlotRange -> {0, 1.1},
 GridLines -> Automatic
 ]
```

[image: With weights]

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to obtain a plot of the CDF (and PDF) but it only works with a constant binwidth of 1 (which I think is a long-standing limitation of `ProbabilityDistribution` for discrete distributions - but I would certainly like to be corrected if that's not true:  [ProbabilityDistribution only accepts dx=1 for discrete distributions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/125314/probabilitydistribution-only-accepts-dx-1-for-discrete-distributions))

```
values = {23, 11, 3}
bins = {0, 1, 2, 3}
dist = ProbabilityDistribution[Sum[Boole[bins[[i]] <= x < bins[[i + 1]]] values[[i]]/(Total[values]),
  {i, 1, Length[values]}], {x, Min[bins], Max[bins], 1}]
Plot[CDF[dist, x], {x, Min[bins] - 1, Max[bins] + 1}, 
 Exclusions -> None]
```

[image: cdf]

```
Plot[PDF[dist, x] // Evaluate, {x, Min[bins] - 1, Max[bins] + 1}, 
 Exclusions -> None]
```

[image: pdf]

(Why `PDF` requires `// Evaluate` to plot correctly and `CDF` does not is a mystery to me.)